# Metro console application in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, console-application

Is there a way to build metro application that runs in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no console in the "Metro*" interface.  There is still a command prompt on the desktop and that has not changed from Windows 7.  This is not going to allow you to run a "Metro*" app, however - it is a command prompt.

I think you may need to do a bit of research into what the "Metro*" UI is, and what it is not.

* This UI is no longer called "Metro", but I have referred to it as such to avoid clouding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a console if you need that in Windows 8, and your console applications will continue to work. But this is not Metro.